# Spekken toy model: measurement of spin in any direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, foundations

[Spekkens' toy model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spekkens_toy_model) [1] can handle the measurement of a spin 1/2 along the directions $x$, $y$ and $z$. Unless I am missing something, it can't handle measurement in any direction. Would there be a known extension providing such a $\psi$-epistemic model that can handle measurement in any direction?

[[1]](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.75.032110) Spekkens, Robert W. (2007). “Evidence for the epistemic view of quantum states: A toy theory”. In: Phys. Rev. A 75 (3), p. 032110.

Comment: Please consider writing more useful question titles, see [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/50583)